# What's the RegExp for date and month?

Tags: javascript, regex, file, date

Filename input examples:

> Yield file 31 July 20.csv
>
> Yield file 30 Aug 20.csv

My `RegExp` code:

```regex
Yield\sfile\s[0-9]{2}\s\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May?|Jun(?:e)?|July?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sept(?:ember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)|Dec(?:ember)?)\s[09]{2}.*\\.([Cc]{1}[Ss]{1}[Vv]{1})$
```

Comment: The character class at the end should be `[0-9]{2}` with a dash, you can omit the `.*` after it and you can also omit `{1}` from the pattern and the word boundary. `^Yield\sfile\s[0-9]{2}\s(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May?|Jun(?:e)?|July?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sept(?:ember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)|Dec(?:ember)?)\s[0-9]{2}\.(?:[Cc][Ss][Vv])$` See https://regex101.com/r/A7cU55/1

Comment: do we not require \b before the month

Comment: You are matching a whitespace char `\s` before.

Comment: You should spend a little more time asking your question clearly. The body should stand on its own, it shouldn't require the title to be understood. You should also provide examples of input and expected output that both passes and fails your test, plus what goes wrong with your code (preferably posted as a runnable snippet in the question).

Answer (score 1):

If your file format is *that* rigid...

- The literal string `Yield file`  (with trailing space)
- The date you want to extract
- The literal string `.csv`

Then you don't need regex. You don't even need to care about the string.

Sure you can validate it, eg.

```
if( !filename.startsWith("Yield file ") || !filename.endsWith(".csv")) {
    throw new Error("Filename doesn't match the expected pattern");
}
```

But really all you need is:

```
date = filename.substring(
    "Yield file ".length,
    filename.length - ".csv".length
);
```

Comment: The OP seems to also want to match the month names, so `/^Yield file \d\d (Jan|January|Feb|February|...) \d\d.csv$/`. The OP is poorly worded.

Comment: Hi there sorry about the wording ! friday rush! i just wanted to know regex for the month name  . so format would be something like 31 June 20. i know for numbers we can state [0-9]{2} but for the text month name i was not sure on!

Comment: My point stands - if you know the month is going to be "whatever is in there", you don't need to match the specific texts.